# find and replace in an VARCHAR using php

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

$participants is a `VARCHAR` in MYSQL and looks like this `q1qq2qq3qq4qq5qq6q`. What I want is to have an if statement that is 
executed if `q$_SESSION["UserID"]q` is found, that is, I want it to find some of the inputs in `$participants` such as `q2q` for instance.
I don't know how to write this. `$_SESSION["UserID"]` is one of the id columns in the MYSQL database and hence equal to a number such as 2.

I tried the following in php

```
if(strpos($participants, q$_SESSION["UserID"]q)){
    echo "succeeded";
};
```

but it doesn't work. Furthermore, I also want to be able to take away `q$_SESSION["UserID"]q` in case it's there. I tried

```
$participants = preg_replace("q{$_SESSION["UserID"]}q", "", $participants);
```

but it doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: if(strpos($participants, "q".$_SESSION["UserID"]."q")) echo "succeeded"

Comment: Are you checking for errors? The `q`s should be throwing something. Your regex doesn't work because the `q` would act as the delimiter not the actual character, alpha characters arent valid delimiters though

Comment: Thats a horrible way of storing data. **refactor** your original concept

Comment: You have an alternative idea RIggsFolly? If yes, please tell me :)

Comment: 1) `serialize()` 2) `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
if(strpos($participants, "q" . $_SESSION["UserID"] . "q") !== FALSE){
    echo "succeeded";
};
```

Or you could use a `LIKE` statement in MySQL e.g.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE participants LIKE "%q2q%";`

However, as RiggsFolly said, this is a horrible way of storing data. Create a participants table with a primary key, a foreign key to your main table and the participant ID.

E.g.

```
participantinstanceid int primary key
instanceid int foreign key -> Your instance table
participantid int foreign key -> participant table
```

This way you can just query the table based off an instanceid to get all of the participants. If you need further assistance with this, I'd be happy to help with a better db structure.